# How do I make ansible-playbook log its output in a machine readable format like xml or json?

Tags: ansible

Looking for information on how to output machine readable output form ansible-playbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using one of the configuration options. For a general overview of configuring Ansible, see [the configuration documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html), in particular the [callback plugin configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html).

Callback plugins change how Ansible provides feedback on the progress and state of tasks. There are several options for JSON output:

1. [JSON output to stdout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/json.html)
2. [JSON to syslog](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/syslog_json.html)

Setting these configuration options can be done either in a configuration file (`ansible.cfg`) or with environment variables (`ANSIBLE_XXX`), depending on what you prefer.
To quote the current documentation:

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be searched for in the following order:

> ```
>    ANSIBLE_CONFIG (environment variable if set)
>    ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
>    ~/.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
>    /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
> ```

> Ansible will process the above list and use the first file found, all others are ignored.

Assuming you want to send the output to stdout then, your `ansible.cfg` could look like:

```
[defaults]
callback_whitelist=json
stdout_callback=json
```

Using environment variables:

```
 ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_WHITELIST=json ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook ...
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Comment: If instead of ansible-playbook you want to use the `ansible` ad-hoc CLI, make sure to also set `ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=1`.

Comment: In 2021, ansible 2.11 deprecated the "whitelist" variable and instead renamed it to "enabled" i.e. `ANSIBLE_CALLBACKS_ENABLED`. But I think JSON is enabled by default now.